# CERTBOT ERROR when i make this (ubuntu 16.04) : sudo certbot --apache -d mysite.com

Tags: certbot

The following error occurs when running:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d mysite.com
```

Is there any reason this could occur?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/bin/certbot", line 7, in 
>       from certbot.main import main
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 2, in 
>       from certbot._internal import main as internal_main
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 9, in 
>       import configobj
>   ImportError: No module named configobj

Comment: Which version of certbot are you running? Could you try updating it?

Comment: > `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`
Latest Certbot requires Python3